# crash in core data xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

i am facing an issue in IOS swift Xcode 8

after i setup my Core Data and before i insert any junk data in purpose of testing the fetch function the app run correctly with no crash and no data but after i insert a data the app crash with below message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0x7f9b26054c00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Deatials.
```

here is my code

```
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

       // the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate needed to start woring    in all the function for datacore

     class MainVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

// definning the main view the table and the segment.

@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!

// need to difine the NSFetchedResultsController to define the remaining 3 functions for the tableview
var controller : NSFetchedResultsController<Item>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    generateTeseData()
    attemptFetch()

    TableView.dataSource = self
    TableView.delegate = self
}


// we need to define 3 main fucntions for the table view

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let sections = controller.sections{
        return sections.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // need to difine number of rows in section by NSFetchedResultsController
    if let sections = controller.sections{
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // linking the cell var with the class of itemCell been created in the View Folder
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellItem", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

    // function been created below:
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}

func configureCell (cell:ItemCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let item = controller.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.ConfigureCellsInCellclass(item: item)

}


func attemptFetch () {
    let fetchrequest:NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    let datesort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)
    fetchrequest.sortDescriptors = [datesort]

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchrequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    self.controller = controller

    do{
       try controller.performFetch()

    }catch{
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error)")
    }

}

// these two function for the update in the tableview
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    TableView.beginUpdates()
}
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    TableView.endUpdates()
}

//this function to preforme all the functions for the <Data Core>
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch(type)
    {
    case.insert:
        if let indexpath = newIndexPath {
            TableView.insertRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)
        }
        break

    case.delete:
        if let indexpath = indexPath{
            TableView.deleteRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)
        }
        break

    case.update:
        if let indexpath = indexPath {
            let cell = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath) as! ItemCell
            configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath! as NSIndexPath)
        }
        break
    case.move:
        if let indexpath = indexPath {
            TableView.deleteRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)

        }
        if let indexpath = indexPath {
            TableView.insertRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)
        }
        break
}
}
```

at this point the system will cun without any crash
but after i add the insert function in below it's start crashing

```
func generateTeseData(){
    let item = Item(context: context)

    item.title = "IMAC"
    item.price = 2000
    item.details = "Soon"
}
```

this is my view cell file

```
class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {


// this view to take all the label from the view and link it here


@IBOutlet weak var thump: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Price: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Deatials: UILabel!


// using this function to set the values of the items with the labels been linked before in upper section

func ConfigureCellsInCellclass (item:Item){
    Title.text = item.title
    Price.text = ("$\(item.price)")
    Deatials.text = item.details
}
}
```

thank you guys in advance

Comment: Your issue isn't related to CoreData, it's about your Xib/Storyboards. You have a bad linked with IBOutlet there for the `UILabel` `Deatials`. Look on your favourite Search Engine for `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[XXX setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXX` where you remove XXX which is specific to your issue but the solution is reproducible.

Comment: Also correct spelling is `Details`

Comment: @Larme thank you for response i just delete all the connections between the IBOutlet and create it from beginning but still crashing ,

i am connecting the IBOulet with view class  from cell view is there any special way to do this

Comment: thank you @Larme 
I fount that in all my IBOutlet I was defining the custom class  with my cell class and after I clear it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @Larme says your problem is related to IBOutlet which is not reflect in class anymore.

Disconnect bad outlet

[image]